# Unity - How to set IK position of Left Hand with an offset?

Tags: unity, animation, vector, inverse-kinematics

I have a character holding a stick with left hand. I am using IK to make the stick hit a target position. When I position left hand at target position, it works fine. But, I need to offset the hand such that the end of the stick hits the target position. For this, I have put an empty game object as a child at the end of the stick, and offset it like in the code below, but the hand just keeps jittering like crazy. I know it is quite possible to do, but somehow I seem to be missing something. Please help me!

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject target;
 private Vector3 leftHandPosition;
 private Vector3 hitChildPosition;
 
 private void OnAnimatorIK(int layerIndex)
 {
         Vector3 t = target.transform.position - (hitChildPosition - leftHandPosition);
         animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.LeftHand, t);
         animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.LeftHand, 1);
 }
 
 private void LateUpdate() 
 {
         hitChildPosition = BatHit.transform.position;
         leftHandPosition = animator.GetBoneTransform(HumanBodyBones.LeftHand).position;
 }
```

Here's an image to visualise what I'm trying to solve -
[image]

Comment: Your code assumes that the offset between the bat and the hand will be the same worldspace vector after the IK step as it is before the IK step. That's not true if the hand/arm needs to rotate to get into position. Let's say on frame 1, that rotation leaves your bat pointing to the left of where you want it. Next frame, the IK uses this new offset to calculate a new position for the hand, further to the right to compensate. This rotates the hand again, so now the bat ends up too far to the right. So next frame it over-corrects to the left again, overshooting each time to create a jitter.

Comment: Okay, so how should I solve this? Could you help by telling me how to correct my code?